# Make a python program an application

Tags: python

I would like to make a Python program executable, like in Windows, when you use a program like `cx_Freeze` to make Python programs become `.exe`. I would like to do the same for Mac, I would like to make it an app...

I know I can put as first line of the file, a sheebang, or that I can change the mode of the file, but this does not make the program an independent application...

Comment: Isn't cx_freeze crossplaform? or use the other apps mentioned on the cx_freeze homepage

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus). It is a developer tool for OS X that lets you wrap your Python/Perl/shell/etc script with an application framework that makes your Python script appear and run like it was a native OS X application.

Though I believe you can do the same thing with Automator, there are a few extra nice things about Platypus from what I remember. For example, you can create a custom icon for the application where I think Automator's output would probably have to be modified after the fact.

Comment: Keep in mind, depending upon how you have your system configured, you may need to manually source your shell configuration files within Platypus to ensure environment variables are correct.

Comment: @tubedogg, yes, you do need to be extra careful in your scripts. For example, make sure you're pulling the correct version of Perl/Python/whatever and that any libraries you're expecting are there as well. My experiments with Perl required me to make sure I was hitting the right version based on OS and 32/64bit-ness. If you're going to distribute it, don't assume someone else has same environment variables. Wasn't hard, but worth being mindful about.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with Automator.

1. Open Automator up
2. Create a new "Application" document
   [image: New Automator document]
3. Add a "shell script" action to your workflow
   [image: Find shell script]
   [image: Drag to workflow]
4. Your shell script should look like this:
   [image: Shell command]
5. Save it wherever! You can put it in `~/Applications` for example.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open automator
2. Add a 'run shell' action
3. There should be a drop down list that says '/bin/bash' click and switch to /usr/bin/python
4. write your text and your set!!!

Comment: How does this differ or improve on the earlier answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153828/237