# python script to create a desktop icon

Tags: startup, python, javascript

Right now I'am using npm start to open a desktop app (i.e nodejs server) which uses electron framework.
So when ever I want to open that desktop app I have to open the terminal, go the application directory and use command "npm start" to open the nodejs server i.e desktop app.

I want to write a python scrip to create a desktop app, and when ever I double click that desktop icon, it should internally uses 'npm start' command to open that desktop app.

Can any one please help me, and my application directory is as:
/Desktop/Electron/charityapp.

Answer (score 4):

- Open Terminal
- `cd ~/Desktop`
- `echo '#!/bin/sh' > run-my-app`
- `echo 'cd ~/Desktop/Electron/charityapp' >> run-my-app`
- `echo 'npm start' >> run-my-app`
- `chmod +x run-my-app`

Then just double-click on the icon on the Desktop

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to [the other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254675):
if you wouldn't like to see a terminal window opening up each time you double click the bash script file you could create an Automator bundle.

1. After opening my favorite option are create an application or a
   service (you can later bind a shortcut to this)
2. Then select, Library → Utilities and double click on Run Shell Script
3. From there, in a couple of my previous I used this setting `Services recives: no input    in: any applications`
4. In the Shell option you can choose `/bin/bash` instead of the in-script `#!/bin/sh` and then add the lines of scripts:

   ```
   cd ~/Desktop/Electron/charityapp     
   npm start
   ```

---

- You could even choose python script here, but in this case I don't know how to help you.
- For a shortcut after saving the you-service-name can be seen in
  System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Services.

Answer (score 0):

Open textedit & paste it:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

def main():
    os.system("npm start")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Save it, remove its extension (using Finder is okay) & run

```
chmod +x /Users/ankii/Desktop/testapp
```

[Python script executable opened by text editor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174889/python-script-executable-opened-by-text-editor?rq=1)